# Multithreading Calling a Delegate

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

To quote Marc Gravell:

```
///...blah blah updating files
string newText = "abc"; // running on worker thread
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
    someLabel.Text = newText; // runs on UI thread
});
///...blah blah more updating files
```

I'm looking to do this with WPF so can't use the `invoke` method. Any thoughts? This Threading stuff is doing my head in :/

**MORE DETAIL**

I began my new Thread like so

```
Thread t = new Thread (LoopThread);
t.Start();
t.Join();
```

But throughout `LoopThread`, I want to write to the UI.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Jon Skeet for the `Dispatcher.Invoke` bit. Seems `MethodInvoker` is WinForms also. WPF equivalent?

**UPDATE 2**

Thanks Adriano for suggesting instead of `System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker`, using `System.Action`.

(You guys were right about the `this` parameter confusion, just need to build to remove errors.)

Bus since adding the `SimpleInvoke`, now I'm hit with

```
Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class
```

on the line

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: About the edit: instead of `System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker` you can use `System.Action`.

Comment: @Adriano Thanks! Still having a problem though, see code above.

Comment: 2nd edit: `SimpleInvoke` is an extension method then you do not need `this` as first parameter. The `this` in the function prototype is just the syntax for extension methods. Change to `this.SimpleInvoke(() => txtDoor1.Foreground = Brushes.Black);`

Comment: 3td edit: LOL :) Take a look to the link posted by @JonSkeet about extension methods. You must create a static class and put the extension method there (you can't declare and use your extension method in your instance-able class).

Comment: @Adriano Thanks I just had to Build to remove the error I was seeing. New error, see above.

Comment: Yes, look the previous comment. Move the declaration of your extension method outside the class where you'll use it (in another static class, follow Jon's example).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In WPF, you just use [`Dispatcher.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx) instead of `Control.Invoke`.

The `DispatcherObject` class (which WPF classes derive from) exposes a [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject.dispatcher.aspx) property, so you just need:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke((Action) delegate {
    someLabel.Text = newText; // runs on UI thread
});
```

If you're using C# 3 or higher (and .NET 3.5 or higher) you might want to add an extension method to `DispatcherObject`:

```
// Make this a new top-level class
public static class DispatcherObjectExtensions
{
    public static void SimpleInvoke(this DispatcherObject dispatcherObject,
                                    Action action)
    {
        dispatcherObject.Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
    }
}
```

So you can just use:

```
// From within your UI code
this.SimpleInvoke(() => someLabel.Text = newText);
```

Comment: @killianmcc: True, I hadn't spotted that. I believe WinForms is optimized very slightly for MethodInvoker, which is why I suspect Marc used it. I've moved to Action instead though for the code in the answer. It's more idiomatic anyway. Fundamentally it doesn't really matter - it's just a parameterless delegate.

Comment: wow looks a lot neater than before. Problem though: `SimpleInvoke` wanted two parameters, so I added `this` in there but still throwing an error. See code above.

Comment: @killianmcc: No, that's an *extension method* which you'd need to place in a static top-level non-generic class (e.g. DispatcherObjectExtensions). I'll edit the post to make this more explicit. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: You're right. I just had to build to remove the error I was seeing. Strange error from it now though. See above.

Comment: Thanks for your patience there Jon, working perfectly now. This Threading business isn't easy!

Answer (score 0):

as compromise using SynchronizationContext:

```
    // gui thread

    var sc = SynchronizationContext.Current;

// work thread

    sc.Post(s => 
    {
    someLabel.Text = newText
    }, null);
```

Answer (score -1):

Continuing from Jon Skeet comment, and you can call your extension like below

```
DispatcherObject.SimpleInvoke(() => someLabel.Text = newText);
```

Comment: No, actually `SimpleInvoke` is an extension method for `System.Threading.DispatcherObject` (and derived), not for `System.Threading.Dispatcher`.

Comment: No, did you try to compile? ;) Actually Jon's answer has an invocation example.